# Изменение TabControl C# WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

Необходимо добавить на `TabControl` `TabItem` с несколькими объектами по нажатию кнопки.
Добавить на `TabControl` `TabItem` можно следующим образом

```
        TabItem tb=new TabItem();
        tb.Header="qwe";
        tabControl.Items.Add(tb);
```

А как добавить на `TabItem` объекты? 
Например `Image` и `ListBox`?

Я не смог ничего найти(или нашел, но не смог понять что это именно то что мне нужно)
Не могли бы вы посоветовать как быть?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Элементы нужно добавлять в какую нибудь панель, а панель привязать к TabItem

```
        var stackPanel = new StackPanel();
        stackPanel.Children.Add(new Image { Height = 20.0 });
        stackPanel.Children.Add(new ListBox { Height = 20.0 });

        var tb = new TabItem();
        tb.Header = "qwe";
        tb.Content = stackPanel;
        tabControl.Items.Add(tb);
```

Comment: А как обращаться к элементам из кода(которые добавили только что)?

Comment: @boikov для этого вместо new Image, как в примере выше, создавайте переменную типа и задавайте ваши контролы ей и добавьте в панель. манипуляции с контролом можно совершать, как до добавления в панель, так и после. Это особой роли не играет.